# How do I prevent array concatenation from changing the values of the arrays involved?

Tags: arrays, ruby, concatenation, ruby-2.4

I want to create some constants that are array values, but seem to be having a problem when I try and concatenate them.

```
MALE_TOKENS = %w(m male)
#=> ["m", "male"]
FEMALE_TOKENS = %w(f w female)
#=> ["f", "w", "female"]
GENDER_TOKENS = MALE_TOKENS.concat FEMALE_TOKENS
#=> ["m", "male", "f", "w", "female"]
MALE_TOKENS
#=> ["m", "male", "f", "w", "female"]
```

Notice that after the `concat`enation, the `MALE_TOKENS` now contains the `FEMALE_TOKENS`.  I don't want this.

How do I keep things separated?

Comment: Why not use `+`?

Comment: I suggest just one tag here: `ruby`. I don't see anyone search on any of the other tags.

Comment: I wouldn't advise it, but you could write `[].concat(a).concat(b)`, which would not alter `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Array#`concat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-concat) mutates the receiver:

> Appends the elements of +other_ary+s to `self`.

To not change the `MALE_TOKENS` value you can use [Array#`+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-2B):

```
GENDER_TOKENS = MALE_TOKENS + FEMALE_TOKENS
#=> ["m", "male", "f", "w", "female"]

MALE_TOKENS
#=> ["m", "male"]
FEMALE_TOKENS
#=> ["f", "w", "female"]
```